# Error in thread 'main' panicked at 'Building libffi',

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, toml, libffi

System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Wayland). I am trying to build a simple rsmpi code (Rust+MPI), but I am unable to build it because of the error : thread 'main' panicked at 'Building libffi'.

My Carg.toml file is:

```
[package]
name = "heat_equation_mpi"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
#mpi = { git = "https://github.com/bsteinb/rsmpi", rev = "f9aec8b8d82" }
mpi = "0.5.4"
```

The error shown is:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `libffi-sys v0.6.0`
Caused by:process didn't exit successfully:
..... some lines here ....
  thread 'main' panicked at 'Building libffi', /home/my_name/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libffi-sys-0.6.0/build.rs:27:9
```

Can someone please help?

Note: You can find the entire error log here: https://pastebin.com/8pZPJSvi

Comment: I guess the relevant error is further up in the output. Maybe some required system library is not available, and you need to install it?

Comment: Looks like [running `make install` is failing for libffi](https://github.com/tov/libffi-sys-rs/blob/v0.6.0/build.rs#L50-L53). There should be output from `make` detailing the error further up.

Comment: @SvenMarnach i added the entire log here https://pastebin.com/8pZPJSvi

Comment: Turns out the actual error is at the very bottom: "makeinfo: command not found WARNING: 'makeinfo' is missing on your system." So I guess you need to run `apt install texinfo` to fix this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work for me :(

Comment: Do you get a different error now? Can you try running `makeinfo` to see if the command exists?

Answer (score 0):

Libffi author here.  Sven is right -- your system is missing makeinfo.  On my fedora box, this is provided by the texinfo package.